# How can I access the data stored in a VM on GoDaddy?

Tags: python, database, ssh, report, godaddy-api

I have `n` tables that I have stored in a VM on GoDaddy. Currently, I use MySQL-Front to access the data. However, understandably, this approach is not feasible for programmatic exploration and summarization of the data.

Hence, I would like to know how can I access this data using Python (or any other language) so that I can create some reports based on this data.

I have the host's IP address, port, username, password, and the name of the DB which I am trying to read. For MySQL-Front, this much information is enough to access the DB.

I tried to SSH into the DB using the aforementioned username and password but got the error `Permission denied, please try again.`

Comment: When you connect to the database from a programming language, you specify the hostname of the database server. So use the IP address when you call `mysql.connector.connect()`.

Comment: See the examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to the aforementioned database using MySQL Connector/Python and supplying the IP address, port number, username, and password.

`pip install mysql-connector-python`